# Clean up dates using POWER QUERY?

Tags: powerquery

I have a column that has no data validation to give people more freedom of input, so it's quite messy, i want to make it more neat.

Original

| Target Date |
| --- |
| Q2 2021 |
| Jan 2022 |
| Dec 2023 |
| 06-2017 |
| Q3-2018 |
| Q3 - 2019 |
| *7 Jan |

Is there any way to clean it up to the best you could to become like this using Power Query (or other functions in Excel if needed)?

| Target Date |
| --- |
| Jun 2021 |
| Jan 2022 |
| Dec 2023 |
| Jun 2017 |
| Sep 2018 |
| Sep 2019 |
| *7 Jan 2021 |

*i know this is difficult xd

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Review code's steps:

1. Convert data to Excel Table
2. Remove extra spaces
3. Conditionally extract the year portion checking if its a Number or not
4. Extract the quarter portion If you can build a date from year and quarter portions, then do it, otherwise analize the Target Date column and see if it returns a date
5. Remove other columns
6. Rename remaining column
7. Add formatted date column

---

**M Code:**

```
let
    Origen = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    TrimText = Table.TransformColumns(Origen,{{"Target Date", Text.Trim, type text}}),
    ExtractConditionalYear = Table.AddColumn(TrimText, "Year", each try Number.From(Text.End([Target Date], 4)) otherwise Date.Year(DateTime.LocalNow()), Int64.Type),
    ExtractQuarter = Table.AddColumn(ExtractConditionalYear, "Quarter", each Number.From(Text.Middle(Text.AfterDelimiter([Target Date], "Q"),0,1)), Int64.Type),
    CalcDateFromQuarterOrAnalize = Table.AddColumn(ExtractQuarter, "Date", each try Date.AddDays(Date.AddQuarters(#date([Year], 1, 1), [Quarter]), -1) otherwise Date.From(DateTimeZone.From([Target Date])), type date),
    RemoveOtherCols = Table.SelectColumns(CalcDateFromQuarterOrAnalize,{"Date"}),
    RenameCol = Table.RenameColumns(RemoveOtherCols,{{"Date", "Target Date"}}),
    AddFormatDateCol = Table.AddColumn(RenameCol, "Format Target Date", each Date.ToText([Target Date], "MMM yyyy", "en-US"), type text)
in
    AddFormatDateCol
```

---

Result

[image]

Let me know if it works